# Using https with decoupled front-end and backend MEAN applications that run on same host

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, https

I have a MEAN project in which the Angular front-end application is decoupled from the backend Node + Express + MongoDB application. Each application is committed to its own git repository and can be staged or deployed independently.

The problem I have is that the applications are being deployed from the same host and both applications desire to use the https protocol.  Are there best practice approaches to allowing the two apps to use the same protocol with default port number 443?

One option that has been suggested is to use nginx to proxy to selected port numbers (eg., 3000 for the front-end and 3001 for the backend).  Is this best practice or are their better options available?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0. I will try the approach suggested to see if it works.